# VBScript Folder name of the extract zip file

Tags: vbscript

I am able to unzip a file by using the below codes.

```
sUnZipFolder = ABC.zip

set sFilesInZip = objShell.NameSpace(sZipFileNamePath).items
objShell.NameSpace(sUnZipFolder).CopyHere(sFilesInZip)
```

How can I figure out what the name of folder that got extracted?

For example: Zip File name is ABC.zip and inside that ABC zip file contain one folder called XYZ. After I unzipped the ABC.zip. How do I capture the folder name XYZ? XYZ folder name changes monthly, because it is a service pack that get download monthly.

Comment: It is your code, shortened a bit to much IMO. The files should reside in `sUnZipFolder` and subfolders if they were part of the zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason you cant just use `sFilesInZip(0)` but you can enumerate it to find the folder.

```
for each x in sFilesInZip
    folder = x
next
msgbox folder
```

Comment: The name sUnZipFolder is different from the folder that is inside it. For example: Zip File name is ABC.zip and inside that ABC zip file contain one folder called XYZ. After I unzipped the ABC.zip how do I capture the folder name XYZ? XYZ folder name changes monthly, because it is a service pack that get download monthly.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've modified the solution.

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for the tip!